# Who would generate Token using oAuth and Asp.Net web api?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin, identityserver4

We have a website, where users need to login to the system to see their content. 
After login, we have a href-URL ,while user clicks on that link it is redirecting to our vendor site's login page.
We need to avoid login page in our Vendor Website since the users of our website are allowed to access our Vendor Resources without login. 
I need to implement the Token based authentication  to our Vendor website using OAuth,ASP.NET API.

Since we need to directly login to our Vendor site, who would be generating the Token?.

Here is my approach/steps based on my understanding

Step 1. On click of href-URL, from [OurWebsite], Sends  https://[vendorAPI]?client_id=[ourwebsite_id]&username=[username] to Vendor. 
        Vendor Understands that there is a request coming from [OurWebsite].

Step 2. [OurVendor] Requesting a Token from Our Website  using  https://[ourwebsiteapi]/oauth/token. 
            Using POST, they have to submit username,password and grant_type. 
            Vendor gets the response token,  Expires(hrs) etc.

Step 3. After Authenticating the Token by  [Vendor], it sends back same Token in https://[ourwebsiteapi]/oauth/responsetoken?token=[TOKEN] to [OurWebsite].

Step 4. Once [ourwebsite] confirms the Token , then it opens up the http://[vendorwebsite]?token=[token] web site.

I believe my job is just need to generate the Token and give it to our vendor , Our vendor Authenticate the Token and provide us the URL to be opened.

Comment: Does the vendor know the users? Is the vendor a website or an API?

Comment: Yes, vendor knows the users. Vendor is a website.

Comment: I assume the users can login at the vendor website? So currently they have to login at both your website and the vendor website? But not with the same password? I mean, your website and the vendor do not share the same usertable.

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Currently user have to login in both website. We wanted to skip login into vendor website.

Comment: The problem with the token is that only the issuer can decode it. And since there are two parties, one of them cannot check the token. So you'll need an authority to issue the token that is accepted by both vendor and your website. Please take a look at IdentityServer: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/index.html Please let me know what you think of that.